# Reading variable with smarty engine

Tags: php, class, smarty

I am quite new to Smarty and I have some trouble. I have a PHP class, let's call it `A`. In `A`, there is a method, call it `M`, in which I want to grab a variable,(`$var` taking an integer value `1` or `2`), and use it on an HTML page, call it `mypage.html`, which is part of another HTML page, call it `MyPage.html`.

In the same method, I assign my HTML code in a smarty assign like this:

```
$this->mySmarty->assign('content', $this->fetch('mypage.html'));
```

and then I display:

```
$this->display('MyPage.html');
```

But strangely, when I assign a smarty variable, `var` to my PHP variable `var` like this:

```
$this->mySmarty->assign('var', $var);
```

...the page `MyPage.html` doesn't recognize the following:

```
{if $var==1}<span>blabla<span>{/if}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? Is it an incorrect smarty syntax?

Comment: where is the code "{if $var==1}<span>blabla<span>{/if}" ? is it in mypage.html ?

Comment: hi, yes it is in mypage.html !

Comment: @Newben, what is the page showing? Is it ignoring your conditional, or simply not processing the smarty code?

Comment: No, it is just ignoring the conditional. Best

Comment: second <span> should be </span>

Comment: why do you use $this sometimes and $this->mySmarty in other places ? Aren't display() and fetch() methods of the mySmarty object ?

Comment: Yes of course there is </span> in my code. Sorry I made an error when writing the post. Best, Mehdi

Comment: fetch is a method of a smarty object.

Comment: More precisely, I have just made a test : when I write {if $var==0}<span>blabla</span>{/if}, the conditional is read, but 'var' takes only values 1 or 2. Strange isn't it ?

Comment: Are you sure $var only takes values of 1 or 2? `var_dump($var);`

Comment: I think $var is not yet assigned in your control flow, so $var = null => $var == 0

Comment: It'd be better to provide the code in context.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you seem to do

```
$this->mySmarty->assign('content', $this->mySmarty->fetch('mypage.html'));
```

before the variable is assigned. you should try

```
$this->mySmarty->assign('var', $var);
$this->mySmarty->assign('content', $this->mySmarty->fetch('mypage.html'));
$this->mySmarty->display('MyPage.html');
```

but it feels somewhat non-natural to pre-render a template and then assign it to a variable. Check @ddlshack solution for something more smarty-minded.

Comment: Great !! it worked just fine. So by means of your answer, I understand what the bugg was exactely . Thanks, Newben

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use [Smarty's include](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl) function rather than rendering a template then assigning it to a variable.

```
$this->mySmarty->assign('contentTemplate', 'myPage.html');
```

Then

```
{include file="$contentTemplate"}
```

---

Regarding your problem, the code is correct, so the value of $var must not be what you expect.

```
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try :-)! Best,Newben